# How to plot a self-define array?

Tags: arrays, plot, series

I want to plot 3-party data (like funding fee) in tradingview like this:

```
var mySerise=array.new_int(100,0)
array.set(mySerise,0,2)
array.set(mySerise,0,6)
[100 times]......
plot(mySerise)
```

but it's hard to do with too much data. Is it possible to do like this?

```
var mySerise=array.new_int([2,6,11,2,4,5,6])
plot(mySerise)
```

Answer (score 0):

done.

```
array.from(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```